# Getting correct URL to make ajax call from JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working with an ASP MVC app. I created a clients.js file that has an ajax method that calls a controller and then retrieves the data. My problem is that the URL where that page sits looks something like this:

```
http://my.clients.com/GST/2015-4/LEBIN/Profiles/ClientProfile/Index/79
```

In my ajax method i have

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ClientProfile/UpdateClient",
  context: ..
  data: ...
}).done(function() {
  ...;
});
```

therefore, using that format i get

```
http://my.clients.com/GST/2015-4/LEBIN/Profiles/ClientProfile/Index/79/ClientProfile/UpdateClient
```

But i need:

```
http://my.clients.com/GST/2015-4/LEBIN/Profiles/ClientProfile/UpdateClient
```

Also if i add a / before the url like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/ClientProfile/UpdateClient",
 ...
```

It formats the URL like this:

```
  http://my.clients.com/UpdateClient
```

How can i obtain the correct path?, i just need to replace the `/Index/83` with the correct action `/UpdateClient` without funky replaces or logic..

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

The reson why i would not like to just add the whole url part.. is because /2015-4/ part might change several times

Comment: In that case why can't you point the url to `/GST/2015-4/LEBIN/Profiles/ClientProfile/UpdateClient`..?

Comment: /2015-4/ part might change several times

Comment: You should pass to ajax  "/GST/2015-4/LEBIN/Profiles/ClientProfile/UpdateClient"  if you want to hit the right action. If you have more than one call to the controller you can put the part "/GST/2015-4/LEBIN/Profiles/" to global variable and just concat the rest of url.

Comment: Or you can create object in javascript and pass the the path form mvc view which is output of @Url.Action

Comment: Thank can you elaborate on the object example if you do not mind.. that might be what i am looking for...  I am using jquery by the way.. Thanks for the input Grissom.

Comment: this might work.  `../../UpdateClient` as you have `/Index/79`

Comment: you  need to use html5 data attribute with element on page, on even of which you are sending ajax call and in event get url from data attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comment:

yourJsFile.js:

```
var AjaxCallToController = {
    callAjax: function(url){
        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           context: ..
           data: ...
           }).done(function() {
           ...;
           });
    }
}
```

And in yourView.cshtml

```
<script>
AjaxCallToController.callAjax('@Url.Action("UpdateClient", "ClientController"');
</script>
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

just use ../, that way you go back 1 folder, so it should look something like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../../../ClientProfile/UpdateClient",
  context: ..
  data: ...
}).done(function() {
  ...;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by defining a default `site URL` by adding it to the main template header then call it inside any `.js` file as follow:

**Define header URL:**

```
<script> var site_url = '<?php echo site_url() ?>';</script>
// define the <?php echo site_url() ?> in your main PHP config file.
```

**Then inside your javascript files, you can call that URL in different ways, for example:**

```
window.location = site_url +'dashboard';
```

or

```
jQuery.post(site_url + 'account/forgot', jQuery(this).serialize(), function (res) {
    // your code here
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: site_url + 'home/newsletters'
});
```

Thank you